# recover an app from stack or app in background

Tags: android, stack, android-notifications

I have a small application with two activities.

The first activity has a button, pressing this button opens a second activity (the first is paused)
This second activity launch notification.

With the notification released, leave the application by pressing the "home" button and let the application on the stack or in background.

When I click on the notification, I want the application to retrieve the activity that was on the screen.

I am recovering the application using the package name:

```
Intent intent = null;
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        try {
            intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("hello.com.vierco.pruebas");
            if (intent == null)
                throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.putExtra("hola", notificationData);;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        }
```

I get retrieve the application, but always opens the activity number "one" because is reopening.

Someone can tell me how I can retrieve the application? retrieve it from the stack, not open it again. there is any intent?

Wear two days trying without success, I have also searched many forums but without success

A practical example would be grateful because I'm going slightly mad

Comment: can you share code for creating notification.. because you can always specify the name of activity which you want to get open on notification click while creating notification ...

Comment: now that you mentioned, I managed to find the way.
Thank you very much for the guidance :)